# How to find x,y position of Component in React native

Tags: react-native

How do I find out the x,y position of where an element is positioned on the screen, I'm using React Native v0.14. I have tried the following but it says measure is not a function.

```
componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(this.measurePosition);
  },
measurePosition() {
    this.refs.q.measure((a, b, width, height, px,py ) => console.log(width))
},
```

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure what the answer is, but I'd start looking at this blog, where I know he does a lot with x,y coords, so his examples may yield you answers
http://browniefed.com/

Answer (score 8):

**Option1:**

You can use the NativeMethodsMixin. Make sure you've added the mixin to your class

```
var NativeMethodsMixin = require('NativeMethodsMixin')
...
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  mixins: [NativeMethodsMixin]
...
componentDidMount: function(){
  this.refs.element.measure((x,y,w,h,pX,pY) => console.log("dets"))
}
```

**Option 2**

You can use the onLayout property on Views. It is available on most components.

```
render:function(){
... 
<View onLayout = {this.onLayout} />
...
},
onLayout:function(event){
  console.log(event.nativeEvent.layout)
}
```

You will get the x,y, width and height

Comment: This gave me the height and width of my View component which is useful too, however it still doesnt give me the top offset position of my View.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't understand how that is different form y

Comment: The Y comes back with 0, I don't think it's finding the Y of the parent, so where my element fits in the body/document

Comment: In that case the NativeMethodsMixin will come handy. Updated the answer to reflect the same

Answer (score -6):

Can you use something like
1. get the browser DOM element using (ReactDOM.findDOMNode())
2. Use the elements getBoundingClientRect()
3. You have top, left, bottom and right coords

this may also be useful [Retrieve the position (X,Y) of an HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element)

Comment: the question was about react native, not react dom